# sass --watch doesn't check if the file is empty, just if the file exists?

Tags: applescript, eof

??

```
sass --watch source.scss:destination.css
```

doesn't seem to check if the file is empty, only if the file exists

??

The goal is to force `sass --watch` to **always** compile.

I tried:

```
on deleteFile(theFile)
   set eof of theFile to 0
end
```

theFile shows empty, but sass --watch doesn't re-compile.

Telling "Finder" to delete the file is easy, but I'd prefer to avoid the potentially loud sound with deleting the file.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You stated that one solution would be to delete the file using *Finder* **`delete`**, but the loud noise was undesirable.

Instead, use *System Events*:

```
tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to 
    delete the file named "~/path/to/file.ext"
```

Be aware that this deletes the file permanently, akin to `rm` on the command line (which you could use instead if you’re working from there anyway).  It doesn’t send the file to the trash.